# Die Unterschiede zwischen "ausgenommen" und "rausgenommen"

Tags: meaning, difference, verb, preposition

Ich habe ein paar Angebote von meinem Amazon-Lagerbestand entfernt.

Natürlich kann ich einfach so sagen. Im Sinne: *"I took down a couple of listings from my inventory"*. Aber meine Liebe zu deutscher Sprache kennt keine Grenze, deswegen möchte ich das Verb **ausnehmen**/**rausnehmen** benutzen und die Unterschiede zwischen den beiden kennenlernen.

> Ich habe ein paar Angebote vom Lagerbestand rausgenommen (oder ausgenommen?)

Ich vermute, dass ich beide Formen benutzen kann, und "raus" verstärkt nur "aus".

Zum Beispiel, in einem "Alles muss raus"-Sale bedeutet es eigentlich, dass "alles ***aus*** dem Laden verkauft werden muss", oder?

Answer (score 4):

Es heißt: "Ich habe ein paar Angebote aus dem Lagerbestand herausgenommen."
Umgangssprachlich sagt man gern "rausgenommen" statt "herausgenommen", aber das sollte man schriftlich immer mit "heraus" formulieren.

Das Wort "ausgenommen" gibt es nur als Übersetzung für "excluded" oder "gutted", das heißt, man kann es nicht für "herausgenommen" (herausnehmen) verwenden. "Ausnehmen" ist auch das deutsche Verb für "to gut". "To exclude" wird eher mit "ausschließen" übersetzt, d.h. der Infinitiv "to exclude = ausnehmen" ist sehr ungebräuchlich.

Comment: *ausgenommen* heißt auch *exceptional*.

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzend zu @äöü könnte man noch hinzufügen:

Von '*ausnehmen*' / '*to gut*' leitet sich ein figurativer Gebrauch ab:

> Der deutsche Steuerzahler wird **ausgenommen wie eine Weihnachtsgans**.

Das heißt, er wird vom Staat "wie eine Zitrone bis zum letzten Tropfen ausgequetscht", so dass dem armen Menschen praktisch nichts mehr zum Leben bleibt.

Diese Art von '*ausnehmen*' tritt auch nicht-vergleichend als '***jemanden ausplündern, ihn um sein (letztes) Hab und Gut bringen***' auf:

> "Das ist bloß der Anfang. Wenn du ihr bei diesem Kleid nachgibst, wird sie dich bis auf den letzten Cent ausnehmen. Glaub mir." (Desperate Housewives)

Auch ein floskelhaftes '*nicht ausnehmen*' im Sinne von '***durchaus einbeziehen***' tritt als reguläres Verb auf:

> Jeder macht mal Fehler, da will ich mich gar nicht ausnehmen.

Außerdem gibt es **'*ausgenommen*' als** vor- oder nachgestellte **Konjunktion**:

> Jeder kann teilnehmen, Mitarbeiter ausgenommen.
>   Ausgenommen der Chef waren alle dafür.

Diese Konstruktionen können auch als zu Partizip-Nebensätzen umgeformte selbständige Sätze (oder Nebensätze) aufgefasst werden:

> Jeder kann teilnehmen, Mitarbeiter sind davon ausgenommen (/ wovon Mitarbeiter allerdings ausgenommen sind).
>   Wenn man den Chef (mal) ausnimmt, waren alle dafür.

Schließlich gibt es noch '***sich irgendwie ausnehmen***' im Sinne von '*sich irgendwie darstellen, irgendwie wirken, einen bestimmten Eindruck machen*':

> Gegenüber einem Riesenkonzern wie Siemens nimmt sich dieses Unternehmen mit seinen 1.100 Mitarbeitern wahrhaft klein aus.

Comment: +1 für "sich ausnehmen". Das hatte ich noch vergessen. :)